# Cannot login back into GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 user account after some inactivity

Tags: gnome, login, password

After some inactivity screen goes black. When I move mouse or type anything this screen appears:

[image: login window screenshot]

And when I input my password which is I 100% know is correct, I cannot access my account, screen just blinks and password field is blank.

Anyone else has faced this issue?
How to fix that?

Specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- GNOME Shell 3.28.3